# Reading Arrow Feather files in C++

Tags: pandas, apache-arrow, feather

I've scoured the Arrow docs, but haven't found much clarity on how to read Feather files generated via pyarrow back into C++.

```py
import pyarrow.feather as feather
feather.write_feather(df, 'test_file.feather')
```

Is this not a recommended flow? It looks like Feather is on the path to deprecation in favor of Parquet...

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do that, you need to refer to the C++ API for Feather

https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/cpp/src/arrow/ipc/feather.h

Writing additional documentation about this doesn't seem to be a priority but you are welcome to contribute some.